# Drupal 7 Computed field

Tags: drupal-7, computed-field

I am learning Drupal 7 computed field. According to web sources they say i should use `$entity` instead of `$node` for Drupal 7.

I have a content type product with custom fields field_price and field_discount. I need a computed field `field_finalprice = field_price - field_discount`.

As a first step I am just trying to assign field_discount to my finalprice so I created a computed field with code

```
$entity_field[0]['value'] = array_pop(array_pop(field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, 'field_discount')));
```

I do not get any value. Please provide any links that uses computed field for drupal 7.

Answer (score 1):

There is an update in the comments IIRC http://drupal.org/node/1271050

```
$entity_field[0]['value'] = $entity-> field_price[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] - $entity-> field_price[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']
```

should work